# How to use dd to clone a disk but exclude some partitions?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, dd

How to use dd to clone a disk but exclude some partitions?

So I got (on a Raspberry Pi 4B):

```
Device         Boot     Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1           8192     532479    524288   256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2         532480  227000319 226467840   108G 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p3      227000320 1000144895 773144576 368.7G 83 Linux
```

I want to backup the whole system to a file (maybe `pi.img`), so I can restore if needed.

But how to backup `/dev/mmcblk0p1` and `/dev/mmcblk0p2` **only**? (exclude`/dev/mmcblk0p3` because it is a partition with a lot of videos, and 368GB is just too big.)

If I can't to this with `dd`, are there any other options? thanks.

Comment: backup the two partitions, and the first 8192 sectors of the raw drive ... or backup the first 227000320 sectors

Comment: You don't need to use `dd`. Do you mean "_clone_" or "_backup_"? They mean slightly different things

Answer (score 0):

*"backup the first 227000320 sectors"*

Start backing up the whole /dev/mmcblk0p disk, but stop copying at the end of /dev/mmcblk0p2.
Which is counted as 227000320 sectors.

**NOTE**: in your above input a fundamental information is missing, so I assume you have this:

**Units**: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

**Sector** size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

This tell us what exactly the unit and sector numbers represent (512 bytes).

Backup process by dd default settings (bs=512, or equally bs=1b) as visible below. However this command takes too long, due to the small bs value, and so the lot of IO access. We need an optimized command. (This code is only for better understanding):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p of=/backup_folder/RasPiBackup_1b.img bs=1b count=227000320 status=progress
```

**NOTE**: parameter **'1b'** is equal to **'512'**. You can interchange them, as you wish. See source of info later bellow.

As per description https://www.landoflinux.com/linux_dd_command.html:

b=512 |
K=1024 |
M=1024 * 1024 |
G=1024 * 1024 * 1024

In your case:
bs -> count |
1b -> 227000320 |
1K -> 113500160 |
1M -> 110840 |
1G -> 109

In my (Pi4 4GB) system the fastest copy speed comes between bs=1M and bs=4M.

**### BACKUP BEGIN ###**

So the optimized command looks like this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p of=/backup_folder/RasPiBackup_1M.img bs=1M count=110840 status=progress
```

Restore the image

```
sudo dd if=/backup_folder/RasPiBackup_1M.img of=/dev/mmcblk0p bs=1M status=progress
```

**OR**

Backup with pigz (Parallel Implementation of GZip), to save a substantial amount of space and to make compression time 2.5 faster!
The pv command is to show progress

```
sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p bs=1M count=110840 | pv | pigz > /backup_folder/RasPiBackup_1M.img.gz
```

Restore the pigz image

```
pigz -d  /backup_folder/RasPiBackup_1M.img.gz | pv | sudo dd of=/dev/mmcblk0p bs=1M
```

**### BACKUP END ###**

**### IMAGE MANIPULATIONS BEGIN ###**

VERIFY image content

```
sudo fdisk -l /backup_folder/RasPiBackup_1M.img
```

MOUNT image /dev/mmcblk0p1 partition (8192 * 512 = 4194304) to see its content

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/RasPiBackup-mmcblk0p1
sudo mount -o loop,offset=4194304 /backup_folder/RasPiBackup_1M.img /mnt/RasPiBackup-mmcblk0p1
```

MOUNT image /dev/mmcblk0p2 partition (532480 * 512 = 272629760) to see its content

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/RasPiBackup-mmcblk0p2
sudo mount -o loop,offset=272629760 /backup_folder/RasPiBackup_1M.img /mnt/RasPiBackup-mmcblk0p2
```

REMOVE 'GHOST' partition information about /dev/mmcblk0p3

**NOTE:** partition mmcblk0p3 was not backed up, but the image file still contains configuration information about it. We can remove it easily. (Ignore *Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!*)

Print available partitions within the image file:

```
sudo parted /backup_folder/RasPiBackup_1M.img 'print'
```

/dev/mmcblk0p3 will be the partition 3, so delete it directly:

```
sudo parted /backup_folder/RasPiBackup_1M.img 'rm 3'
```

SHRINK to remove unused spaces from the image, to reduce image size, so it can fit to smaller SD card, as well.
https://github.com/Drewsif/PiShrink

```
sudo pishrink.sh /backup_folder/RasPiBackup_1M.img
```

COMPRESS to have smaller size in your /backup_folder, in case you preserve more instances of RasPiBackup_1M.img.
Parallel Implementation of GZip: https://github.com/madler/pigz

```
pigz /backup_folder/RasPiBackup_1M.img /backup_folder/RasPiBackup_1M.img.gz
```

LIST the contents of the archived file, without extracting it

```
pigz -l /backup_folder/RasPiBackup_1M.img.gz
```

**### IMAGE MANIPULATIONS END ###**

Comment: +1; @PiTech, I think your answer is good. I was looking for the paragraph where you repair the partition table (remove entry for the partition, that was not copied), and yes, it is there. By the way, I have checked that the method works both for MSDOS- and GUID- partition tables. - Finally, please edit the answer by rendering the command lines as `code` by indenting each line 4 spaces (or mark the lines and use the icon `{}` in the field above the editing window) and remove the highlighting asterisks).

Comment: @treuss: dd's default block size is 512 BYTES, indeed. **NOTE**: parameter **'1b'** is equal to **'512'**. You can interchange them, as you wish.

Comment: @sudodus: thanks. The whole text has been reformatted to render the command lines as `code`.